# How to construct an SQL query for finding which company has the most employees?

Tags: sql-server, relational-database

I have the following tables and I would like to find the company which has the most workers. I am fairly new to sql and I would like some help on constructing the query. Any briefing would be appreciated on which keywords to use or how to begin with writing the query. I would like to

“Find the company that has the most workers.”

worker(worker_name, city, street)

work for(worker_name, company_name, salary)

company(company_name, city)

manages( worker_name, manage_name)

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us some effort

Comment: I did this so far but I really am stuck and dont know how to complete it.
select company-name
from work-for T
where ( select count(worker-name)
from work-for S
Where T.CompanyName = S.CompanyName )
>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will get you the company with the most employees in it.

```
select top 1 company_name, 
       count(*) as nbr_of_employees
from   work-for
group by company_name
order by 2 desc
```

For more detailed answer please add sample data to your question and expected result.

how it works:
the `group by company_name` will group all records with the same company_name togheter. Because of that the `count(*)` will give you the number of records in work-for for each group. (thus all workers for each company)

the `order by 2 desc` will make sure that the company-name with the most employees is on top of the lists

Finally, the `top 1` in the select will only return the first record in that list

Comment: I actually need to only list the company which is the most crowded and not a list of all companies with employee numbers.

Comment: I kindly thank you for your answer. I would be really happy if you could also elaborate and explain how it works. It is not straight-forward for me since I am a newbie.

Comment: @dazoar Again I edited my answer, hope you find it usefull. there are many sites on the internet you can use for teaching basic sql. Just google it